# Erro ao conectar no banco de dados atraves do Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, conexão, connectionstring

Estou tentando adicionar um banco de dados a minha aplicação, a primeira eu consegui, porem ao tentar adicionar outro banco de dados é me retornado o seguinte erro:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.

Essas são minhas 2 connectionsString, porem somente consegui add a primeira (ASP_NET_MVC_CS):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ASP_NET_MVC_CS" connectionString="Data Source=ARTHUR\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASP_NET_MVC_DB.mdf; Persist Security Info = True; User ID=sa;Password=*******; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="IndetityDB" connectionString="Data Source=ARTHUR\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\IdentityDb.mdf;Persist Security Info = True; User ID=sa;Password=********; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Qual o motivo do erro?

Comment: Isso parece erro de rede ou processo do SQL parado no servidor.

Comment: Verifique se as configurações de acesso do segundo banco de dados (o que não funciona) estão iguais ao primeiro banco de dados (que funciona). E outra coisa, você não escreveu errado isso "IndetityDB" não deveria ser "IdentityDB"? Ou isso está errado "IdentityDb.mdf".

Comment: putsss me desculpe a falha, o erro era justamente esse, estava erra o nome. Muito  Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Sem problemas! @Desalex